# Get Google or Yahoo API live option price

Tags: web-applications, finance, stocks, yahoo-finance, google-finance

Is there a way to get the live options information from Yahoo or Google's API. By options information I mean: call, ask volume. I basically need the information on this [page](http://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=MSFT)

thanks for your help!

Comment: You can obtain option data manually via [CBOE](http://www.cboe.com/DelayedQuote/QuoteTableDownload.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do it other than scraping the HTML.  The `getOptionChain.yahoo` function in the [quantmod](http://www.quantmod.com) R package does that.  You can get the [source](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantmod/index.html) on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/).

Comment: thanks for your answer Joshua, but I would need to retrieve the information without scraping the HTML and I would need it in real time, is there any other way?
thanks!

Comment: @Nick: outside of purchasing the data from a vendor, no.

Comment: yes I'm willing to buy the data from a vendor, do you know some that are in real time and have options data?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language you are looking to use, but you can use the java parser found [here](http://greatwebguy.com/programming/java/stock-quote-and-chart-from-yahoo-in-java/) and modify the Yahoo Finance API link + special tags as shown [here](http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm) and you should be able to get the options information.

As far as I remember there is a 20mins delay in the quotes. I'm not sure if it works the same way for options.